# using the vector class

Tags: c++, vector

I'm still learning the vector class and I want to know why I can't

```
void displace(unsigned int place)
{

    stack.erase(place);
    distances.erase(place);

}
```

I'm being told I need an iterator.  What can an iterator do that an int can't?

Comment: Do you understand arrays, and the difference between an index and a pointer into the array?

Answer (score 0):

Because an overload taking an index would be redundant. Given an index, you can easily get corresponding iterator:

```
stack.erase(stack.begin() + place);
distances.erase(distances.begin() + place);
```